# Motion of Test Charge in EM Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, maxwell-equations

I have a negative infinite sheet of charge moving at a velocity $v$ in the $+x$ direction. A test charge $Q$ with mass $m$ moves at a constant velocity $v$.
[image: EM Situation]
**My Question is simple**: How will the test charge $Q$ move? Will it keep going in the $+x$ direction at a constant velocity $v$, as if no electromagnetic forces act on it? Will it go in a diagonal motion? Did I even get the Force-Body Diagram right?
[image: Free Body Diagram]
With Gauss' Law and a Cylinder as my Gaussian Surface & Ampere's Law and a Rectangle as my Amperian Loop, I've found that
$$\begin{array}{l}
\vec{F}=Q(\vec{E}+\vec{v} \times \vec{B}) \\
\vec{F}=Q\left(\frac{\sigma}{2 \varepsilon_{0}}-\vec{v} \times \frac{\mu_{0} \sigma_{s}}{2}\right) \rightarrow \vec{F}=Q\left(\frac{\sigma}{2 \varepsilon_{0}}-\frac{\mu_{0} v^{2} \sigma}{2}\right).
\end{array}$$
Taking the integral gives me $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{y}(t)=\hat{j} \frac{Q \sigma t^{2}}{4 \varepsilon_{0} m}\left(1-\frac{v^{2}}{{{(\mu}_{0}{\varepsilon}_{0})}^{2}}\right)$

My equations don't meet my intuition -- shouldn't the positive test charge just slam into the negative sheet of charge due to the electrostatic attraction?
Again, my main question is: **How will $Q$ actually move?**

Comment: Minor point: shouldn't your z-axis point the other way for a right-handed coordinate system?

Comment: @Shrey Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Newton's second law?

Comment: @BioPhysicist Sure, with $\vec{F}=m \cdot \vec{a}$, I can derive the $\vec{a}$ of $Q$, from which I can take the integral twice to retrieve the $\vec{v}(t)$ and $\vec{d}(t)$ functions for the test charge. Nevertheless, that does not answer my main question -- which is **How does $Q$ move?**

Comment: @Joeseph123 For a Stationary Observer, $\exists \vec{B}$ and $\vec{E}$, no? That's why my Force equation includes both. For a Relative Observer in motion at a velocity $v$ with the Charged Sheet, there only $\exists \vec{E}$. To my knowledge, at least.

Comment: @DarkRunner Then I guess I don't understand your question... Are you not just asking for $\mathbf r(t)$? Or are you asking some deeper "philosophical" question about "how does the particle actually move?"

Comment: @BioPhysicist Sorry if I was unclear. Here's what I'm trying to do: simulate the actual motion of $Q$ in the EM field. Indeed, I find that $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{F}=\left(2\left(\frac{\sigma}{2 \varepsilon_{0}}-\frac{\mu_{0} v^{2} \sigma}{2}\right)\right.$. But again, I'm thoroughly confused -- my equations don't meet my intuition -- shouldn't the positive test charge just slam into the negative sheet of charge? (I've added this to the original question for clarity)

Comment: I still don't understand. How can $r=F$? Do you know about differential equations? Finding $r(t)$ given the force and initial conditions is just an exercise in differential equations. You need to specify what your conceptual issue is in determining $r(t)$. Just asking someone to solve the problem for you is not on topic here.

Comment: @BioPhysicist That was a typo; I've edited the question and the previous comment. Nevertheless, I retrieved $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{y}(t)=\hat{J} \frac{Q \sigma t^{2}}{4 \varepsilon_{0} m}\left(1-\frac{v^{2}}{{{(\mu}_{0}{\varepsilon}_{0}}^{2}}\right)$ as the position function of $Q$.

Comment: So you are just wanting someone to check your work? That is also off topic.

Comment: @BioPhysicist No, please see the question; I'm genuinely confused as to why the test charge $Q$ doesn't just slam into the negative sheet of charge. Is the Magnetic Force holding it back? Does momentum keep it going at a velocity $v$ in the $+x$ direction? Or does it actually fall to the charged sheet, but in a parabolic curve? Essentially, I'm trying to analyze/understand the motion/path of $Q$

Comment: So then this would amount to checking your work to make sure your expressions, diagrams, etc. are correct first. For example, your B field is in the wrong direction, although the magnetic force is correct (it is incorrect based on the incorrect field direction). I also feel like you didn't solve the differential equations correctly, but this site isn't intended to point out calculation errors.

Comment: @BioPhysicist My $\vec{B}$ is in the right direction, no? Imagine the Infinite Sheet decomposes into an infinite set of wires. Each wire has a current going in the $\hat{i}$ direction. Therefore, by the Right Hand Rule, we have that $\vec{B}$ must traverse in a circular direction "counterclockwise" around the wire. Take the tangent at the test charge $Q$, and we find that $\vec{B}$ is indeed in the $-\hat{k}$ direction. In addition, I've checked once again and I feel confident I retrieved the correct equation for $\vec{r}(t)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112778/discussion-between-biophysicist-and-darkrunner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually thinking of two reference frames, not one frame of reference:

**Reference Frame 1**: where the charge and the plane are moving with velocity $\vec v$, as an observer, **you are static** with respect to the coordinate axes you drew in your diagram. In this frame, the charge experiences **two** forces, an electric force and a magnetic force.

**Reference Frame 2**: where the charge and the plane are static, as an observer **you are moving** with respect to the coordinates axes you drew in your diagram such that the charge and the plane look still...in better phrasing: you are moving with the charge and plane. In this frame, the charge experiences only **one** force; the electric force, there is no magnetic force in this frame.

The magnetic and electric forces are NOT the same in all reference frames.  To calculate these forces in different reference frames, you need to study Special Relativity. Using special relativity, you will find that there is no ambiguity in the motion of the particle. The physical path described by the particle motion is the same, regardless of your frame of reference.

I haven't practiced relativity in a while, so I'd rather leave it to someone else who is better prepared. Please do not accept this as an answer, this is just clarification. I'd leave it someone else to fully answer your question.

Comment: Even though I was cognizant of this fact, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is not consistent with your analysis, but it occurs to me that if you go to a coordinate system which is moving in the x direction with velocity v, then there is no magnetic field, and the test charge will accelerate toward the sheet.

Comment: Would that particle motion be consistent for a stationary observer, or does it only apply to a observer moving with the charged sheet?

Comment: I can't believe that changing the choice of coordinates would make a difference in the motion of the charge. A “stationary” observer should see the charge moving up along a parabolic path which curves toward the negative sheet.